# php: how to parse graphQl query string to get the operation names

Tags: php, graphql

I would like to allow certain graphQl operations only for certain api users based on a confguration. Our stack is Symfony 6.2 + [overblog/GraphQLBundle](https://github.com/overblog/GraphQLBundle).

My current approach is to check in the `authenticate` method of a custom authenticator, if the current operation is cleared in the allowed operations config of the user. For this I would like to parse the graphql query into a kind of array, that I can interpret easily.

Anybody knows how this can be done? I was scanning the underlying [webonyx/graphql-php](https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php/) library, but can not see how they do it.

As a simple example:

```
query myLatestPosts($followablesToFilter: [FollowableInput], $limit: Int, $offset: Int) {
  my_latest_posts(followablesToFilter: $followablesToFilter, limit: $limit, offset: $offset) {
    ...PostFragment
    __typename
  }

  my_roles
}
```

From this I would like to retrieve the operations `my_latest_posts` and `my_roles`.

**Update 1**

it's probably possible to write a simple lexer utilising [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) - I'm just hesitating, as I'm sure someone has done this already... [The spec](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Appendix-Notation-Conventions) appears to be well defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so it turned out [webonyx/graphql-php](https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php/) has indeed all the lowlevel function needed for this :D. Especially the [Visitor](https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php/blob/master/src/Language/Visitor.php) is very useful here.

With this code you can drill down the query to get the operation names (or selections, as they are called in the code)

This works for me:

```php
use GraphQL\Language\AST\NodeKind;
use GraphQL\Language\Parser;
use GraphQL\Language\Visitor;

// whatever comes before
// ...

$graphQlRequest = json_decode($request->getContent(), true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

$operations = [];

Visitor::visit(Parser::parse($graphQlRequest['query']), [
    NodeKind::OPERATION_DEFINITION => function ($node) use (&$operations) {
        // $node contains the whole graphQL query in a structured way
        $selections = array_map(function ($selection) {
            return $selection['name']['value'];
        }, $node->toArray()['selectionSet']['selections']);

        foreach ($selections as $selection) {
            $operations[] = $selection;
        }

        return Visitor::stop();
    }]
);

print_r($operations);
```

The result of `$operations` is then for my example above:

```
Array
(
    [0] => my_latest_posts
    [1] => my_roles
)
```

And this information is all I need to decide weather the user should have access to the endpoint or not.